# Split Button Listview with right text

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

i have something like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rqwq/22/)

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
            <li><a href="index.html">
                <h3>TEST LEFT | TEST RIGHT:</h3>

                </a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
            </li>
</div>
```

My problem is i would like to have the "right text:"
on the right side next to the gear button.

The order should be "lefttext" then blank, depending on the width of the button and then the "right text" next to the wheel

How can i do that?

OR:

two buttons side by side, each of which contains a text without a gear button

Thanks

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i've got this part right:

> The order should be "lefttext" then blank, depending on the width of the button and then the "right text" next to the wheel

Is this is what you are looking for?

```
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
        <li><a href="index.html">
            <h3><div style="float:left;">TEST LEFT</div> <div style="float:right;">TEST RIGHT:</div></h3>

            </a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to arange the fields like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vleran/3Rqwq/456/) or just alight something inside them?

if you want to arange the list like i did in jsFiddle this is what you add:

```
#myCustomGroup > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width:50%;
}
```